# Is there any way to test an Angular directive with many parameters

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm in stuck on finding the right way to write unittest for angular directive with many parametters.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('svt')
        .directive('elementInteractor', draggable);

    draggable.$inject = [
        '$document', 'settingConst', 'rpElementEditorSvc', 'reportElementDataSvc', 'reportPageSvc', 'reportEditorSvc',
        'angularScopeUtilSvc'
    ];

    function draggable($document, settingConst, rpElementEditorSvc, reportElementDataSvc, reportPageSvc, reportEditorSvc,
        angularScopeUtilSvc) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                pageData: '=',
                questionData: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var maxzIndexToReset = settingConst.report.maxzIndexToReset;
                var minElementSize = settingConst.report.minElementSize;
                var draggablePageConfig = {
                    padding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderColor: '#244f95'
                };
                var resizeConstants = {
                    main: 'resize',
                    left: 'resize-left',
                    right: 'resize-right',
                    top: 'resize-top',
                    bottom: 'resize-bottom',
                    topLeft: 'resize-top-left',
                    topRight: 'resize-top-right',
                    bottomLeft: 'resize-bottom-left',
                    bottomRight: 'resize-bottom-right'
                };
                var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
                var isResizeMode = false,  resizeClass = '', width = 0, height = 0;
                var orginalX = 0, orginalY = 0, orginalZ = 0;
                var elementPosition = {};

                init();
              .......
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

And I've tried to write by this way but it didn't work

```
describe("Testing elementInteractor directive", function () {
    var element, scope, $compile,
        $document,settingConst,
        rpElementEditorSvc, reportElementDataSvc, reportPageSvc, reportEditorSvc, angularScopeUtilSvc;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ngMockE2E'));
    beforeEach(module('svt', '../page/reportPage.html'));


    beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, $rootScope, $injector) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        scope.questionData = {};
        scope.pageData = {};
        $document = $injector.get('$document');
        settingConst = $injector.get('settingConst');
        rpElementEditorSvc = jasmine.createSpyObj('rpElementEditorSvc', ['getzIndexMax']);
        reportElementDataSvc = jasmine.createSpyObj('reportElementDataSvc', ['updateElementSize','updateElementPositions']);
        reportPageSvc = jasmine.createSpyObj('reportPageSvc', ['getWorkingElementIds', 'getEditingElement', 'setDeselectedElementId', 'setSelectedElementId']);
        reportEditorSvc = jasmine.createSpyObj('reportEditorSvc', ['setShowedMarginPageId']);
        angularScopeUtilSvc = jasmine.createSpyObj('angularScopeUtilSvc', ['safeApply']);
        $compile = _$compile_;
        element = angular.element(
            '<div element-interactome page-data="page-data" question-data="question-data"></div>');
        $compile(element, {
            $document: document,
            settingConst: settingConst,
            rpElementEditorSvc: rpElementEditorSvc,
            reportElementDataSvc: reportElementDataSvc,
            reportPageSvc: reportPageSvc,
            reportEditorSvc: reportEditorSvc,
            angularScopeUtilSvc: angularScopeUtilSvc
        })(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it("should display the values", function () {
          .....
    });
});
```

Any guy here can help me find the way to write unittest efficiently in karma and jasmine environment.

Comment: **How** didn't it work? What are you expecting that incomplete code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: I mean, the unittest didn't get through inside the directive when trying to debug by karma. I don't know how to make it get through the complex directive like that and I'm finding the sample for my case though.

Comment: Most of sample I get from Google just show the direction for simple directive without the passed parameters.

Comment: "get through inside the directive" doesn't mean anything. And karma is not a debugger. Be precise. What output do you expect, what output do you get instead?